# scale_fill_discreteで凡例内のラベルを変更したい

Tags: r, ggplot2

3つの年齢階層における疾病の件数の経年変化を示す線グラフを書こうとしています。

元データが横長なので

```
elderlytrendw<-melt(elderlytrend, id.vars = "Year", variable.name = "Age", value.name = "Case")
```

縦長にし、`legend.labels<-c("65-74", "75-84", "85+")`で凡例内のレベルを指定しています。

```
Fig2<-ggplot(elderlytrendw,aes(x=Year, y=Case))+geom_line((aes(colour=factor(Age))))+scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(2000,2016, by=1), limits=c(2000,2016))+scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 9000, by=2000), limits=c(0,9000))+ylab("Number of cases")+ggtitle("Figure 2. TB notification among the elderly, 2000-2016")+theme_classic()+labs(color="Age group")+scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set2")+scale_fill_discrete(name="", labels=legend.labels)
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

ですが凡例内のラベルが変更されません。指定の仕方が間違っているのでしょうか。どなたかご教示頂ければ幸いです。

Answer (score 2):

おそらく，labelsを設定するのに`scale_fill_discrete`を使っているのが原因だと思います。

```
library(ggplot2)
legend.labels <- c("hoge", "fuga", "piyo")

ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = Species)) +
  scale_color_discrete(labels = legend.labels)
```

[image: 実行後の出力]

上述のコードのように，`scale_color_discrete`を利用すれば，凡例内のラベルを変更できるかと思います。