# ggplot2で凡例ラベルと色を変更する方法

Tags: r, tidyverse, ggplot2

[R ggplot2 scale_fill_discreteで凡例内のラベルを変更したいのですが](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/37964/r-ggplot2-scale-fill-discrete%E3%81%A7%E5%87%A1%E4%BE%8B%E5%86%85%E3%81%AE%E3%83%A9%E3%83%99%E3%83%AB%E3%82%92%E5%A4%89%E6%9B%B4%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84%E3%81%AE%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%81%8C)

上記ページを参考に、凡例ラベルを変更することはできました。
これに加えて、色指定はどのように実行すればよいでしょうか。

```
library(ggplot2)
legend.labels <- c("hoge", "fuga", "piyo")

ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length)) +
geom_line(aes(color = Species)) +
scale_color_discrete(labels = legend.labels) +
scale_color_manual(values=c("red","blue","orange"))
```

このスクリプトでは、

> Scale for 'colour' is already present. Adding another scale for 'colour',
>   which will replace the existing scale.

というエラーメッセージが返され、色の指定は適用されますが、
凡例ラベルは適用されません。

どのようなコードを用いれば色指定した上で凡例ラベルを変更できるのか、
ご教授のほど、よろしくお願いいたします。

[image: iris]

Answer (score 2):

`scale_color_manual()`の引数に`labels`を追加すればできます。

```
iris %>% 
 ggplot(aes(x = Sepal.Length, 
            y = Petal.Length, color = Species)) +
 geom_line() + 
 scale_color_manual(values = c('red','blue','orange'),
                    labels = c("hoge", "fuga", "piyo"))
```

Comment: ご教授いただき、ありがとうございました。
おかげさまでしたい作図ができるようになりました。

ついでに書きますと、散布図でプロットの形指定も凡例と色指定のに加えて実施したかったのですが、
scale_shape_manualでカッコを閉じ忘れていたことが原因であったこともわかり、
二重で感謝です。